# Running puckel/docker-airflow image on Raspberry Pi

Tags: docker, docker-compose, raspberry-pi, airflow

1. Why are some docker images incompatible with platforms like Raspberry Pi (linux/arm/v7)?
2. Furthermore, can you modify a Dockerfile or another config file such that it is compatible?

Thanks for any suggestions!

---

So far I've [installed docker and docker-compose](https://devdojo.com/bobbyiliev/how-to-install-docker-and-docker-compose-on-raspberry-pi) then followed the [puckel/docker-airflow readme](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow), skipping the optional build, then tried to run the container by:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 puckel/docker-airflow webserver
```

got this warning:

> WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm/v7) and no specific platform was requested

found [this issue](https://github.com/dani-garcia/bitwarden_rs/discussions/1264) and ran:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --platform linux/arm/v7 puckel/docker-airflow:latest webserver
```

then, this error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: image with reference puckel/docker-airflow:latest was found but does not match the specified platform: wanted linux/arm/v7, actual: linux/amd64.
> See 'docker run --help'.

Comment: Which version of Docker are you running? `docker --version`. It appears that version 20 has some issues, and I've had luck downgrading back to version 19

Comment: thank you for the tip I will check to see if this works

Comment: After more investigation, it was due to not having QEMU support. Docker Desktop includes these by default, but my Ubuntu/AWS machines did not. I installed these packages and it started working. Here is the tutorial I followed: https://www.stereolabs.com/docs/docker/building-arm-container-on-x86/

Comment: I'm still having a bit of trouble but it seems like emulating an architecture with `QEMU` and the `buildx` command are the general solution to my issue. I'm still trying to figure out how to piece it all together. Thanks! ([docker blog post](https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-platform-docker-builds/))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Executable files, i.e. binary files, are dependent on the computer's architecture (amd64, arm...). Docker's image contains binary files. That is, the docker image is computer architecture dependent.

Therefore, if you look at the registry of docker, the OS and Architecture of the image are specified. Refer to the [dockerhub/puckel/docker-airflow](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/puckel/docker-airflow/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated) you used, `linux/amd64` You can see it only supports. In other words, it doesn't work in arm architecture.
If you want to run this arm architecture there will be several ways, but the point is one. It is to build the result of building the origin code with arm, not amd64, as docker image.

---

In [github.com/puckel/docker-airflow](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow), guidelines for building are well stated.

First, if you look at the `Dockerfile` provided by the github, it starts from the image `FROM python:3.7-slim-buster`. For the corresponding `python:3.7-slim-buster`, it supports `linux/arm/v5`, `linux/arm/v7`, `linux/arm/v5`, `linux/arm64/v8`. [dockerhub/python/3.7-slim-buster](https://hub.docker.com/_/python?tab=tags&page=1&ordering=last_updated&name=3.7-slim-buster)

In other words, you can build to arm architecture

I have experience creating images for multiple architectures through the docker buildx command. Of course, other methods exist, but I will only briefly introduce the commands below.

---

[dockerhub/buildx](https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/)

- docker buildx is an experimental feature, and it is still recommended `Experimental features must not be used in production environments`.

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm/v5,linux/arm/v7 .
```

Comment: thanks for the response. so the binary can be modified through the docker command line tool but cant be found as a directory on the filesystem, correct?